# Salesforce API Prevent Read Access

Tags: rest-api, standard-objects

We've provided to our partners to post leads via REST api (using oauth refresh token)

```
"services/data/v3x.x/sobjects/Lead"
```

However, we don't want partners to have access to "read" leads.  I tried disabling read permission from profile or "permission set" but no luck.  Looks like if you select "create", "read" is automatically enabled and if you try to disable "read", then "create" is disabled.

If can't do this via permissions is there another way like prevent http "get" method?  If "get" is a way to do this, where would this be disabled?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the standard Lead api which works off profile/permission set access.

One way to do this is to create your own api, and create leads using that. You can grant access to that api to required partners.

Since inside apex code, you can access objects irrespective of profile/permission set, you will be able to insert.

Comment: Thanks datasert!  I figured, kind of sucks though.  I took this project over and to expedite re-used the API stuff previous dev did.  Figured I'd have to create my own apex.

Answer (score 0):

Two non-code solutions.

## Make Leads Private

You could set the Lead Organization Wide Defaults to Private, and optionally reassign the Lead records on creation to another user. They will still be able to use GET calls, but it won't matter, since they can only retrieve records they have access to.

## Phantom Object

Create a Custom Object, and use the Process Builder to create a Lead whenever they create one of these custom object records (and, optionally, delete the record afterwards). This way, you don't need to muck with your Lead Sharing Settings, and instead just give them access to the Custom Object. The Process Builder is all point-and-click, but you'll have to remember to map the fields if you add new fields they can use.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox!  Since this is a new service for the company, I think I'll do it correctly the first time.  I'll create a separate custom service and only allow "create".  (another sad thing the previous dev did was 1) provide the service using oauth but username/password flow (not recommended) and 2) set this user to sysadmin...wow :-(  ).

Comment: @user20719 I'd avoid going down the road of writing code if you can help it. The real solution should involve setting up a user with limited permissions, setting up security/sharing, etc.